# uninstall a module and its installed service using foreman puppet in Ubuntu

Tags: puppet, foreman

I have been playing with foreman for quite a while and now facing a problem with uninstalling modules.

When I try to uninstall a module using "Delete" button in Managing Class screen, I got an error that says "Module already used by host". Yes I understood, because its already mapped to host. I then revoked the module from host and deleted this module. This deletion happens only in foreman.

But I want to uninstall the service installed by foreman/puppet by puppet run (puppet agent -t ).

Do I have to use module's uninstall configuration, set appropriate values to params and do a puppet run to uninstall service before I delete module from foreman ?????

For example:
 If I install apache with apache puppet module, it manages apache service, conf files, etc.... Now I want to completely remove apache service from all machines connected to my network.

Comment: What do you mean by 'uninstall service'?

Comment: Matt, I updated question, please see the example

Comment: So you want to undo a module deployment?

Comment: Yes... correct. ..

Comment: Matt, any updates on this ???

Comment: should I rely on ensure=> absent ????